# TMRpcm playback and analogread issue on Arduino

Tags: audio, arduino

I am working on an Arduino toy (using Uno). When people press the Force Sensitive Resistor, it triggers the .wav audio which is played by the TMPpcm library.

However, I realized once the audio is played the analogread from the FSR got messed up.
(the value on the FSR no longer goes back to 0, instead, it's stuck with some numbers.

I tried to set it back to 0 at the end of the function. didn't work.)

also tried with digitalread with thick buttons, it's fine. But I really would love to use the thin FSR so I can put it in papers.

Any thought?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Put a resistor from the positive side of the "button" to ground. Should pull the value down to zero.